# Java Serial read/write Raspberry

Tags: java, serial-port, raspberry-pi, modem

I'm writing an application that communicates with a 3G modem over serial port.

When I test my application with modem connected on my laptop I receive from serial port only modem responses.

When I run the same application on Raspberry I receive from serial port commands that I write and modem responses. ( I'm using event based reading from serial port ).

I'm using JSSC, Java 1.7 and Raspberry Model B with Noobs 1.3.

What can I do to receive only modem response without messages that I write to serial port ?

Comment: Seems like *local echo* is enabled on the RPi's serial port, which you want to disable.  Try `stty -F /dev/ttyxxx -echo` before you run your program.

Comment: Thanks @sawdust, I tried your command but not working. I need a command to turn off local echo for all time ( not until reboot ).

Comment: You can add a command to be executed at startup in ```/etc/rc.local```. Try ```stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 115200 raw -echo -echoe -echok -echoctl -echoke```

Answer (score 0):

I always use this blogpost: http://www.irrational.net/2012/04/19/using-the-raspberry-pis-serial-port/
(you need to modify cmdline.txt and inittab)